# adding imports to objc bridging headers

Tags: objective-c, swift, stripe-payments

I have been having an issue with using objective-c files in my swift project. I have come to the realization that I had already imported an objective-c file. So instead of importing another file, I decided to update the previous imported obj-c file with one more #import "STPAUBECSDebitFormView.h". this is for using stripes services.

photo below,

[image: image1]

sorry for the false highlight, its STPAUBECS that I am having with.

with importing this file, I am getting hit with the 'STPMultiFormTextField.h' file not found and failed to emit precompiled header. However, if I were to remove that

## import "STPAUBECSDebitFormView.h" I am hit with the image below,

[image: imGE2]

I am trying to understand how to use multiple languages inside of swift. would really appreciate it if someone could help me understand how to use stripes obj-c language inside of swift.

Comment: Have you been following stripe's instructions?  https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic
You can use their cocoapod.  Those integrate very easily in with Swift.

Comment: What version of the Stripe iOS SDK are you using?

Comment: @floatingLomas I am using the latest one

Comment: @floatingLomas is that not the correct version?

Comment: Probably is.  As HalR said it should work just fine in Swift so I'd recommend just following the documentation.